# How to use QtSingleApplication?

Tags: qt

1. MacOSX10.8 + Qt5.1 with clang 64bit
2. Create Qt Gui application
3. in the main.cpp I just add `#include <QtSingleApplication>`

---

**Compile error:**

```
../untitled/main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'QtSingleApplication' file not found
#include <QtSingleApplication>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

---

What did I miss?

---

Additional information
project file has already set `QT += widgets`

I google already, it seems need `qtlocalpeer.cpp,qtlocalpeer.h,qtsingleapplication.cpp, qtsingleapplication.h,qtsinglecoreapplication.cpp,qtsinglecoreapplication.h`, but how to generate these files?

some posts said it needs include `qtsingleapplication.pri`, but where is it? I searched my disk I cannot find it.

---

**reference**
[SinleApplication from Qt](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtsingleapplication/)

[QtSingleApplication Class Reference](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtsingleapplication/qtsingleapplication.html)

[Sample by Qt](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtsingleapplication/qtsingleapplication-example-trivial.html) but where to download source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QtSingleApplication is not an official part of Qt, but rather a class that was released alongside it if people were interested. (All the "*Qt Solutions*" were additional classes that weren't actually part of the official Qt libraries)

Not only was it not part of Qt, but Qt is now on version 5, and it depended on deprecated Qt4 functions. You'll probably need to write it yourself, or modify someone else's code. [Here would be a good place to start](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22994). There also might be an updated version in the [Qt Solutions Archive](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions).

An important question to ask, though, is: Does your application **really truly** want to **force the user** to **never** have more than one copy of the application running at once?

Doing it just because it's cool is not actually beneficial to the user. You are removing a really nice *feature* built into Windows, hampering your application's use - so think carefully before deciding that it's something you actually want to add!
It'd be better to add features, not *remove* them, unless you can't help it in this case. And if you can't help it, whatever features this *cost*, this *loss*, gains the user better be worth it! =)

Comment: exactly I forget it's Mac not Windows. In this case, I just use normal QApplication instead of QSingleApplication to avoid some troubles. thanks

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for a better alternative to the `QtSingleApplication` class, especially one that works on `Qt5+` and supports `QtQuick` take a look at the [SingleApplication](https://github.com/itay-grudev/SingleApplication) project.

It uses `QSharedMemory` to ensure no race condition occur and is really easy to use. You just replace the call to `QApplication` with `SingleApplication` similar to how `QtSingleApplication` works:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SingleApplication app( argc, argv );

    return app.exec();
}
```

It also uses Local Sockets to notify your original (first) process for the initialization of a new one so the parent can raise it's window.
The dull documentation and code are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/itay-grudev/SingleApplication).

Among other things it supports sending messages between the newly spawned instance and the primary instance. In this example new instances send  the primary instance a message containing their arguments.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SingleApplication app( argc, argv, true );

    if( app.isSecondary() ) {
        app.sendMessage(  app.arguments().join(' ')).toUtf8() );
        app.exit( 0 );
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

QtSingleApplication has now been ported to Qt 5:

https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtsingleapplication

Comment: How can I use it? I'm stuck coz I can't find the `QtSingleApplication` class anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that no one has actually given you the solution about the include error. So, if you use cmake, and I guess you do these days with Qt, as they switched to it, then you can do this in your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
find_package(QtSingleApplication REQUIRED)
```

Then, you use the following cmake command to add your dependency:

```
add_executable(MySingleApplication main.pp)
target_link_libraries(MySingleApplication PUBLIC QtSingleApplication::QtSingleApplication)
```

Then, you include it like this:

```
#include <QtSingleApplication/qtsingleapplication.h>
```