# Make a SingleApplication in Qt

Tags: qt

I have server programm that works fine, listening incoming clients. Hence, I would like to prevent it from duplicate lauch, as I want only the one server to make a service for connected entities, if it's possible?

Comment: In the same machine or _anywhere_?

Comment: Can't really help you, but I would maybe start reading about process management... In the sense of _having just one process_ for your server running at a time...?

Comment: You want to avoid some process before the second bind on your socket make your application failed? Because you will not be able to make two processes on a same machine listens for incoming connections on same tcp port.

Comment: Well, it's not an issue to which TCP port listen to. I would like to throw an exception in case duplicate programms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can lock a specific file using `lockForWriting` method of [QReadWriteLock](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qreadwritelock.html) and keep it locked as long as the application is running and if you can't lock it, exit the application. Since only one instance will be able to lock the file for writing, other instances will terminate themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I am using QSingleApplication -  and it is wroking great.

Source code:

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/source/4ac977553f2b04a54feb74ebcbc90ef255d38895:qtsingleapplication

Example code from there:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    report("Starting up");

    QtSingleCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    if (app.isRunning()) {
        QString msg(QString("Hi master, I am %1.").arg(QCoreApplication::applicationPid()));
        bool sentok = app.sendMessage(msg, 2000);
        QString rep("Another instance is running, so I will exit.");
        rep += sentok ? " Message sent ok." : " Message sending failed; the other instance may be frozen.";
        report(rep);
        return 0;
    } else {
        report("No other instance is running; so I will.");
        MainClass mainObj;
        QObject::connect(&app, SIGNAL(messageReceived(const QString&)),
                         &mainObj, SLOT(handleMessage(const QString&)));
        return app.exec();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this built a library?

Comment: @elgolondrino you should download it and compile it as a library.

Comment: I don't think QSingleApplication works with Qt 5, but for 4.* should be ok: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937618/how-to-use-qtsingleapplication

Answer (score 0):

You can use **synchronization primitives**.
For example: **named mutex**.
When an application is started it check whether mutex with the given name exists if so it notifies user that only one instance is allowed and it is already running, if not so - application starts

Comment: Do you mean QMutex class?

Comment: it can be platform specific Mutex or QMutex if portability is required