# How to make program focused on .exe click when it's opened?

Tags: c++, windows

Some Windows applications like for example Sublime Text 3 get focus on their window when they are opened and you click the .exe file. The thing I'm aiming for is taking focus from any opened app that way. I use Qt5 and C++ for my program. **The key thing is that app should not only have one instance at a time but it should focus on instance that already exists when you double click .exe file**

Comment: To my knowledge, all programs get focus when you manually start them. Could you be more specific on what you are trying to do?

Comment: All program get focus when you start them but not all programs get focus when they are already started and you double click their exe file.

Comment: Oh, are you trying to have only one instance of your program running?

Comment: Yes and I want to get focus on this one instance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937618/how-to-use-qtsingleapplication

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191465/how-to-run-only-one-instance-of-application

Comment: It's not the solution. I want to get focus on existing instance.