# How do you pass command line arguments to an already open program in QT?

Tags: qt, command-line

I'd like to know how to pass command line arguments to an already open program.  So the user runs "backup.exe -job awef" and backup.exe recognizes there is an already open process and passes the argument to the already open process so users can command the program to do what they wish from the command line or a shortcut in windows.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal by using QtSingleApplication that handles the commandline arguments on messageReceived, as per https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtextended4.4/qtopiadesktop/qtsingleapplication.html#QtSingleApplication

At the beginning of your application, you will need to check if you can sendMessage with your commandline arguments to an already running instance, and then quit. Otherwise, you will continue starting your app, as follows

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QtSingleApplication app("MySingleInstance", argc, argv);

  // try to send commandline arguments
  if(app.sendMessage(app.arguments().join("$")))
  {
        return 0;
  }

  /* connect your messageRecieved signal to slot
  SomeClass::slotLoadCommandLine to be able to handle 
  the commandline arguments from sendMessage*/
  QObject::connect(qApp, SIGNAL(messageReceived(QString)),
                   SomeClass, SLOT(slotLoadCommandLine(QString)));

   //start your application
   return app.exec();
}
```

**Edit**

- the solution above is for Qt4, if you are using Qt5 you will need to use 
  SingleApplication instead

  https://forum.qt.io/topic/22460/solved-qtsingleapplication-and-qt-5/5

  [How to use QtSingleApplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937618/how-to-use-qtsingleapplication)
- Another option could be using sockets (e.g. QTcpSocket). But you will need to create a another application that forwards your commandline arguments .. See this example http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTcpSocket_Signals_Slots.php

Comment: @shellter no problem ... we all learning .. thanks for your comment :) !

Comment: Is that class deprecated?  I'm not finding it in the current class documentation or any libraries relating in my program.

Comment: Which Qt version ?

Comment: It's an extension that i used to use in Qt4... You will need to apply the right patch for Qt5..

Comment: Do you think there's a way to do it with QT 5.7 without third party?

Comment: Well, you can do it with sockets. But you will need to create a another app that forwards ur commands.. . See http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTcpSocket_Signals_Slots.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123122/discussion-between-hag-and-josh-orenberg).

Answer (score 0):

A patched QtSingleApplication library for QT 5 is available as discussed here:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/71778/what-happened-to-qtsingleapplication